# Shell script not executing completely and exiting in between

Tags: linux, shell, expect

In the below code (which will run on my linux machine), I am trying to copy `run_check_node.sh` to two different remote linux machine and then executing that script from my machine only.
**Issue**: The `run_check_node.sh` script takes around 25 minutes to execute. But the `run_check_node.sh` script execution on the remote linux machine stops after around 3-4 minutes and then next iteration of `for` loop is taken. Same thing happen in this next iteration also. I tried using `set timeout 1200`, to account for those 25 min, but still same issue. Can anyone please help what to do?

**Question**: The machine IPs I am using, sometimes they ask for password and sometimes don't. So, I am expecting for it. So, in case no password is asked, it simply throws some message on console and below script execution continues. Please tell if this is correct way of handling of whether password will be asked or not?

```
#!/bin/bash

Linux1_ip=10.20.30.40
Linux2_ip=10.100.20.30
pass="Gaur"

IP=("$Linux1_ip" "$Linux2_ip")
home="/post_checks"


############################ Linux_ip CHECKS ####################################
for ne in "${IP[@]}"
do
        expect -c "
           spawn ssh root@$ne \"mkdir /post_checks_$ne\"
           expect yes/no { send yes\r; exp_continue }
           expect password { send $pass\r; exp_continue }
           exit
                "
         expect -c "
           spawn scp $home/run_check_node.sh root@$ne:/post_checks_$ne/
           expect yes/no { send yes\r; exp_continue }
           expect password { send $pass\r; exp_continue }
           exit
                "       
        expect -c "
           spawn ssh root@$ne \"chmod +x /post_checks_$ne/run_check_node.sh; bash /post_checks_$ne/run_check_node.sh\"
           expect yes/no { send yes\r; exp_continue }
           expect password { send $pass\r; exp_continue }
           exit
                "               
    fi
done
```

Comment: When you use ssh from the commandline, and enter nothing in the remote screen, how long will your connection be valid? Can you enter a command after 5 minutes?

Comment: but my run_check_node.sh script is continuously executing commands on the remote host.

Comment: Each command is run in a new ssh session.
Each session will have a timeout that you might see with an interactive shell. Your "set timeout 1200" might not be the solution.
James' solution might work, timeouts can be given by firewalls, remote or local systems, TIMEOUT settings and more.

Answer (score 0):

Now, this may not explain *why* you're seeing what you're seeing, but it may be a useful workaround.

How about you try to execute your `run_check_node.sh` shell script on the remote *in the background*? You would then disconnect and let it complete on its own.

So, basically, your 3rd spawn line would be:

```
spawn ssh root@$ne \"chmod +x /post_checks_$ne/run_check_node.sh; bash /post_checks_$ne/run_check_node.sh &\"
```

If you needed to check on completion of the shell script, what I'm proposing would not be acceptable... but I don't see your Bash script doing any checking on that, so I'm thinking it may work for you.

Try it out and let me know how it goes.

Comment: i want to collect log also from the run_check_node.sh and if i will run this in background, i will not be able to get that :(

Comment: The background process can log in a file. Your collection script can grep/tail the logfiles.